# What's the best way to clear the screen in Perl?

Tags: perl

Ideally, something cross-platform.

Comment: A console screen or a GUI screen?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The CPAN is probably the best way to go.  Take a look at [Term::Screen:Uni](http://search.cpan.org/~tpaba/Term-Screen-Uni-0.04/lib/Term/Screen/Uni.pm):

```
require Term::Screen::Uni;
my $scr = new Term::Screen::Uni;

$scr->clrscr()
```

Answer (score 38):

```
print "\033[2J";    #clear the screen
print "\033[0;0H"; #jump to 0,0
```

Comment: +1000 to this guy, this method does not require the user to install some cpan module (and everything than that implies)

Comment: Doesn't require an install, doesn't happen to work either on some platforms.

Comment: Cool, but what to use at Windows?

Answer (score 11):

I generally use [Term::ANSIScreen](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term::ANSIScreen) from CPAN which gives me all sorts of useful console-related features.

```
use Term::ANSIScreen qw(cls);
cls();
```

Answer (score 8):

From [perlfaq8](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html)'s answer to [How do I clear the screen](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How_do_I_clear_the_s):

---

To clear the screen, you just have to print the special sequence that tells the terminal to clear the screen. Once you have that sequence, output it when you want to clear the screen.

You can use the Term::ANSIScreen module to get the special sequence. Import the cls function (or the :screen tag):

```
use Term::ANSIScreen qw(cls);
my $clear_screen = cls();

print $clear_screen;
```

The Term::Cap module can also get the special sequence if you want to deal with the low-level details of terminal control. The Tputs method returns the string for the given capability:

```
use Term::Cap;

$terminal = Term::Cap->Tgetent( { OSPEED => 9600 } );
$clear_string = $terminal->Tputs('cl');

print $clear_screen;
```

On Windows, you can use the Win32::Console module. After creating an object for the output filehandle you want to affect, call the Cls method:

```
use Win32::Console;

$OUT = Win32::Console->new(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
$OUT->Cls;
```

If you have a command-line program that does the job, you can call it in backticks to capture whatever it outputs so you can use it later:

```
$clear_string = `clear`;

print $clear_string;
```

Comment: `Win32::Console::Cls` does not return a value that you can save.

Comment: How would you change the answer in the perlfaq to account for that?

Answer (score 8):

Under OS X and Linux, you can use the following Perl command:

```
system("clear");
```

<strike>Don't know what the equivalent is under Windows.</strike>

Edit: Windows equivalent is:

```
system("cls");
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are talking about a terminal, I would use something like the Curses lib to do it.

There is a nice Curses module to access it, which you can use like this:

```
perl -MCurses -e '$win=new Curses;$win->clear()'
```

Answer (score 2):

Support Linux and Windows:

```
system($^O eq 'MSWin32'?'cls':'clear');
```

Answer (score 1):

**I disagree with the above**

1. Connecting additional modules = Increase the attack surface.
2. Reduce the Amount of Running Code.
3. Code refactoring.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my
( $over, $cleaning );
( $cleaning ) = qq([J\033[H\033[J);
( $over ) = <<EOF;
 1. Connecting additional modules = Increase the attack surface.
 2. Reduce the Amount of Running Code.
 3. Code refactoring.
EOF

print ($cleaning.$over);

__END__
```

| FOO | BAR |
| --- | --- |
| \033 | stands for ESC ANSI value 27 |
| [J | erases the screen from the current line down screen |
| [H | move the cursor to the home position |

Comment: Great answer, although I would remove the unnecessary `$over` part from the actual code in your answer. They're good motivations to just print `$cleaning` to screen, but not part of the real solution.

Comment: Сharm Perl is that - «There’s more than one way to do it» ;)