# How can I update values on the screen without clearing it in Perl?

Tags: perl

I want to display a set of values on screen and update that value every 5 seconds. I don't want to clear the screen.

eg:

hours: 1

mins : 30

sec: 45

here, values should change accordingly.

How should i do that in Perl?

Regards,
Anandan

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For this sort of thing I like to use [Curses](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Curses). It's just not for Perl, either. :)

Answer (score 14):

Are you talking about getting more control over where things are printed on your screen? Then you probably want to check out the [Term::Cap](http://search.cpan.org/~jstowe/Term-Cap-1.12/Cap.pm) module.

A poor man's way to do this on one line is to use `\r` to keep overwriting the same line.

```
while ($t>0) {
    # note no new line at the end of printf statement
    printf "\rHours: %d  Minutes: %d  Seconds: %d     ", $t/3600, ($t/60)%60, $t/60;
    sleep 5;
    $t -= 5;
}
```

**EDIT** Here's something that works on my system. Your terminal's capabilities may vary.

```
require Term::Cap;
$terminal = Tgetent Term::Cap { TERM => cygwin, OSPEED => 9600 };
$terminal->Trequire("up");  # move cursor up
$UP = $terminal->Tputs("up");
$t = 500;
while ($t > 0) {
    printf "Hour: %d    \n", $t/3600;
    printf "Minute: %d    \n", ($t/60)%60;
    printf "Second: %d    \n", $t%60;
    print $UP,$UP,$UP;
    sleep 5;
    $t -= 5;
}
```

Comment: Don't use \r in these cases. It's a logical character, not a specific bit pattern, so it's not always what you think it is. Specify it as the ASCII character you want instead.

Comment: I've changed this from `ku` (the characters generated by pressing the up arrow key) to `up` (the capability for moving the cursor up).  It's possible these are the same on your terminal, but that's not true in general.

Comment: @briandfoy, I am just curious, could you elaborate on why not to use `\r`? Thats how I would have accomplished this.

Answer (score -4):

Something like this:

```
use Term::ANSIScreen qw(cls);
while(1) {
    cls;

    print "....";

    sleep 5;
}
```

Alternatives of "cls" can be found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197933/whats-the-best-way-to-clear-the-screen-in-perl).