# progress bar in command line perl script

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am trying to print progress in % in command prompt. But it is not working properly.

I want to print the progress as :: Status 10% Completed
when 20% will complete it will show Status 20% Completed
in that same place not in new line. Could you please help me.

Code::

```
$count++;
$per=($count/$total)*100;
print "\nStatus:  $per Completed.\r";
sleep 1;
```

Comment: set $|=1; and remove \n before Status:  btw Term::ProgressBar could be  a good choice

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466648/how-can-i-update-values-on-the-screen-without-clearing-it-in-perl/1466699#1466699

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::HiRes qw(usleep);
local $| = 1;

my @nums = 1 .. 20;

foreach my $c (@nums) {
  print "$c";
  usleep(100000);
  print ("\b" x length($c));
}
print "\n";
```

Answer (score 22):

The module [Term::ProgressBar](http://search.cpan.org/~szabgab/Term-ProgressBar-2.14/lib/Term/ProgressBar.pm) seems to be able to do what you're after.

Note, I haven't tried it.

**Edit** Well, out of curiosity, I have now tried a small script:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Term::ProgressBar;

my $total = 50;
my $progress_bar = Term::ProgressBar->new($total);


for my $i (1 .. $total) {

  sleep (1);

  $progress_bar->update($i);

}
```

It won't exactly print what you asked (eg `Status nn% completed`), instead, it does print a *real* progress bar, something like

```
  10% [=====                                              ]
```

Nevertheless, it seems to most simple and straight forward solution.

Answer (score 3):

Small modification to the original code:
\n and \r are removed and 
added autoflush and "\033[G"  and \033[J

```
$|=1; #autoflush

$count = 0;
$total = 100;
while ($count != $total) {
   $count++; 
   $per=($count/$total)*100; 
   print "\033[JStatus: ${per}% Completed."."\033[G"; # man console_codes, ECMA-48 CSI sequences, "CHA"
   sleep 1
 }
```

Comment: Missing the { for the while but otherwise a good and useful example

Comment: @carbontracking I fixed the missing {. Thank you.