# Perl show updates on long function

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script that runs a SQL query and takes a while for it to pull the information. Is there a way to show some sort of update to let the user know that the program is still running? I was thinking of having it print `.` every couple seconds until the query is complete.

Unfortunately I am not sure how to run 2 functions at once (one for the query, and another for printing the `...`

Comment: You can fork the progress logic, and kill it when query is done.

Comment: Sounds like you need this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300099/progress-bar-in-command-line-perl-script
It suggests a couple different methods including Term::ProgressBar

Comment: Requires second thread or process

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl                                                                         

use warnings;
use strict;
use POSIX qw( :sys_wait_h );

$|++; # See print and print messages in correct order                                       
main();
1;

sub main {
    print "About to Fork\n";

    if (my $pid = fork()) {
        # parent                                                                            
        print "PARENT: Waiting for child\n";
        sleep 1;
        while(waitpid(-1, WNOHANG) > -1) {
            print '.';
            sleep 1;
        }
        print "\n";
        print "PARENT: Child finished\n";
        print "PARENT: Exiting...\n";
    } else {
        # child                                                                             
        print "CHILD: Starting\n";
        run_sql();
        print "\nCHILD: Exiting\n";
        exit 0;
    }
}

sub run_sql {
    # put your sql code here                                                                
    sleep 10;
}
```

This will output:

```
About to Fork
PARENT: Waiting for child
CHILD: Starting
.........
CHILD: Exiting
.
PARENT: Child finished
PARENT: Exiting...
```

Comment: If you `fork` after `connect`ing to your database, make sure to set [`InactiveDestroy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#InactiveDestroy) or [`AutoInactiveDestroy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#AutoInactiveDestroy) on your database handle so you can continue using it after the child process exits. If you're on Windows, I think `fork` is emulated using ithreads, in which case you will need to `connect` *after* the `fork`, since [database handles can't be shared across threads](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Threads-and-Thread-Safety) (the docs also don't recommend using DBI with threads in prod).