# How to print stopwatch updated value?

Tags: perl

I'm newbie to perl , I'm trying to build a stopwatch , so is there is a way that i can update the print statement values without printing the new value in a newline

Comment: yes, it is possible. see example: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=937870 . but you should try to code it by yourself and if you are stuck or getting errors, post your code, so we can help you. please also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: See also [Perl: print back to beginning of line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2774596/2173773) and [How can I update values on the screen without clearing it in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1466648/2173773)